# java program to count the number of words that starts with capital letters

Tags: java

I want to write a program that count the number of words that starts with capital letters. It only count no. Of capital letter not word try this line 
"Hi hOw are yOu"
According to my code output will be 3
But their is only 1 word that starts with capital letter that is 'Hi'...so how can I solve these problem..Please help me with this.

```
import java.util.*;

class Cap
{
    public static void main(String m[])
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=new String();
        System.out.println("Enter a line:");
        s=in.nextLine();
        char c;
        int ct=0;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            c=s.charAt(i);
            if(c>=65 && c<=90)
            {
                ct++;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("total  number of words start with capital letters are :"+ct);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are counting all the capital letters that are entered.
What you want to do is split the line on space and check only for the first letter if it is capital.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s;
    System.out.println("Enter a line:");
    s=in.nextLine();
    int ct=0;
    for(String str: s.split(" ")) {
        if(str.charAt(0)>=65 && str.charAt(0)<=90)
        {
            ct++;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("total  number of words start with capital letters are :"+ct);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should better use `scanner.next();`, which returns the token up to white space in other way a *word*.Now, you can check the first character of String returned by `next()` is in uppercase or not.

For statement *This is StackOverflow* you will have three tokens, `This`, `is` and `StackOverflow` and you can use `String.charAt(0)` on this `String`.

Moreover, you can simply use [`Character.isUpperCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase(char)) method to check whether character is in upper case or not.

Comment: Clear and simple, best answer imo.

Answer (score 1):

import java.util.*;
public class program_6
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String s1;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string... ");
    s1 = scan.nextLine();
    int count=0,i=0,n;
    n = s1.length();
    System.out.println("Size of the string is... " + n );
     if ( null == s1 || s1.isEmpty())
     {
         System.out.println("Text empty");
     }
     else 
     { 
           if( Character.isUpperCase(s1.charAt(0) ))
           {
               count++;
           }
           for (i=1 ; i<n ; i++)
           {
               if (  Character.isWhitespace(s1.charAt(i-1)) && Character.isUpperCase(s1.charAt(i) ) )
                {
                   count++;
                }
           }  
         }

    System.out.println("Number of the word wich starts with capital latter... " + count );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing each character.Instead you can add a space at the begining of the string  and check each character after space if it is in uppercase.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
String s = new String();
System.out.println("Enter a line:");
s = " " + in .nextLine().trim();
char c;
int ct = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
    c = s.charAt(i);
    if (c >= 65 && c <= 90 && s.charAt(i - 1) == 32) {
        ct++;

    }
}
System.out.println("total  number of words start with capital letters are :" + ct);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/xI6HXr)

or better use `scanner.next()` as said by TAsk

Comment: You only check if there are whitespaces before the capital letter...tabs? br?, and if the capital letter is the first one in the String the program will throw an java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @DavidHerrero no it will not check the demo

Comment: sorry..didnt see the `int i=1`, my fault ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = new String();
        System.out.println("Enter a line:");
        s = in.nextLine();
        char c;
        int ct = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            c = s.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)
                    && (i == 0 || Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i - 1)))) {
                ct++;

            }
        }
        System.out
                .println("total  number of words start with capital letters are :"
                        + ct);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all we check on the first position whether it is starts with capital letter or not and it is only for the string which starts with capital letter... If yes then the count will be incremented. Next condition( Which is used for string which start with blank space or any other string) will check that left position must have blank space to start new word and the character must be capital to increment the count variable...

```
import java.util.*;
public class program_6
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s1;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string... ");
        s1 = scan.nextLine();
        int count=0,i=0,n;
        n = s1.length();
        System.out.println("Size of the string is... " + n );
         if ( null == s1 || s1.isEmpty())
         {
             System.out.println("Text empty");
         }
         else 
         { 
               if( Character.isUpperCase(s1.charAt(0) ))
               {
                   count++;
               }
               for (i=1 ; i<n ; i++)
               {
                   if (  Character.isWhitespace(s1.charAt(i-1)) && Character.isUpperCase(s1.charAt(i) ) )
                    {
                       count++;
                    }
               }  
             }

        System.out.println("Number of the word wich starts with capital letter... " + count );
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe next time you should comment on what you did and why you did it. Just pasting some code doesn't help anybody without some kind of explanation on how it works.

Comment: It is the program to find the number of words which starts with capital latter.

Comment: If I ask you to tell me how I can solve problem X, and you give me some code saying "this is the code to solve problem X", it doesn't tell me the basic logic of how the code works.

Comment: First of all we check on the first position whether it is starts with capital letter or not and it is only for the string which starts with capital letter... If yes then the count will be incremented. Next condition( Which is used for string which start with blank space or any other string) will check that left position must have blank space to start new word and the character must be capital to increment the count variable...